# Postgres: replication conflicts with append only table and no interaction from read replica

Tags: postgresql

I'm having trouble with canceled queries because of replication conflicts. Specifically, I get the message `User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed` event if no deletes are happening and the read query isn't even selecting from a table that is being modified.

Here's my test script:

```python
from typing import Any

# pip install anyio psycopg-pool
import anyio
from anyio.abc import TaskStatus
from psycopg_pool import AsyncConnectionPool


async def create_data(*, task_status: TaskStatus[Any] = anyio.TASK_STATUS_IGNORED) -> None:
    # primary
    dsn = 'postgres://...'

    async with AsyncConnectionPool(dsn) as pool:
        async with pool.connection() as conn:
            await conn.set_autocommit(True)
            await conn.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;')
            await conn.execute('CREATE TABLE test (x int);')
            task_status.started()
            x = 0
            while True:
                x += 1
                await conn.execute('INSERT INTO test (x) VALUES (%(x)s);', {'x': x})
                await conn.execute('VACUUM (VERBOSE) test;')


async def read_data() -> None:
    # read replica
    dsn = 'postgres://...'

    async with AsyncConnectionPool(dsn) as pool:
        async with pool.connection() as conn:
            await conn.set_autocommit(True)
            async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                while True:
                    await cur.execute(
                        """
                        SELECT pg_sleep(1);
                        """
                    )


async def main() -> None:
    async with anyio.create_task_group() as tg:
        await tg.start(create_data)
        await anyio.sleep(1)
        tg.start_soon(read_data)


anyio.run(main)
```

I've set `max_standby_streaming_delay = 0ms` on the replica.

If I change the query to `SELECT 1;` I don't have any issues (at least if I run for 30s); with the `SELECT pg_sleep(1);` query I get the error instantly.

Why am I getting the error in this scenario? Every other question I've seen along these lines involves deletes/updates in the primary and queries on the read replica that interact with those rows. Is Postgres unable to stream updates from the primary if *any* query is running on the read replica?

Answer (score 0):

Just because the query on the standby server hasn't accessed a certain table yet is no guarantee that it won't do so before it is done. As a consequence, WAL records that remove row versions that the query *might* still use cannot be replayed. If you have `max_standby_streaming_delay = 0`, that means that the query gets cancelled.

You can increase `max_standby_streaming_delay` to delay replay and let the query finish. Alternatively, you can set `hot_standby_feedback = on` on the standby to keep the primary from removing row versions that might still be needed on the standby, but you will still get replication conflicts on account of buffer pin or lock conflicts.

See [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/streaming-replication-conflicts-in-postgresql/) fore a more detailed discussion.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz. Your article is by far the best source of information out there. I guess what is still unclear to me is what operations exactly cause the conflicts. For example why does running VACUUM create deleted rows if I'm not deleting any rows? I'm only ever appending. Does having a filter in the query that excludes rows that may be deleted help, or is there anything I can do on the query side?

Comment: When you run `DELETE`, the rows are just marked as deleted. `VACUUM` is a "garbage collection" that actually removes the rows. That hapens automatically in the background. If you only `INSERT`, that should not be a problem. What kinds of conflicts do you get? Snapshot? Buffer pin?, Lock?

Comment: With the example above I get `User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed.` even though I'm only `INSERT`ing, not `DELETE`ing. I obviously wouldn't be running `VACUUM` manually in production but it would run eventually so I'm just trying to make this test deterministic.

Comment: Yes, that is `VACUUM`. You must be updating or deleting something somewhere.

Comment: This happens on vanilla postgres instances that I deployed especially for this test with zero data on them and no other connections. If I comment out the `VACUUM` line _or_ the `INSERT` line the error goes away.

Comment: Well, there must be a row version that should be removed. It could also be in a metadata table.

Comment: A metadata table I created (there are none) or one Postgres uses internally, eg for statistics?

Comment: You can set `log_statement = 'all'` to see all statements.